# Get Code Coverage Statistics IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, code-coverage

I am trying to get the code coverage statistics from the .gcda file.
I know similar questions are there but I did not get what I want then.

Till now, I got the .gcda files after some googling on how to do it.
Got Coverstory to read them. Now when I open one .gcda file it will give me the code coverage of that particular file.

Can any one tell me on how to get the statistics of the entire project in a form of matrix?
are there any tools available to read those gcda file and auto generate the report.
Are there any better way to get the code coverage?

Any sort of help would be really helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find this to be very helpful.
[Xcode code coverage](http://qualitycoding.org/xcode-code-coverage/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the Alcove gem:

https://github.com/ioveracker/alcove

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this gem.  Please give it a try and let me know what you think.